# SpeechRecognizer is just staying on onRmsChanged

Tags: android, speech-recognition

```
package com.example.hp.check2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList data;
TextView tv;
Button speakButton;
public SpeechRecognizer sr;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);

    sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    sr.setRecognitionListener(new listener());
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    data=new ArrayList();
}
class listener implements RecognitionListener
{

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onReadyForSpeech", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onBeginningOfSpeech", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onRmsChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onbufferreceived", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onEndOfSpeech", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        String str = new String();

         data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size()+10; i++)
        {

            str += data.get(i)+"S";
        }
        tv.setText(str);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onPartialReults", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onEvent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_speak)
    {
        sr.startListening(new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH));
    }
  }
    }
```

When I am running the code,I am just getting the toast of onRmsChanged and nothing else and it continues till I close the application.And there is no method change when I try to speak as there is no new Toast appearing on the screen.I have read about onRmsChanged on internet but didn't get it much.I have granted the permission of microphone but still the problem occurs.Any idea what is going on?

Comment: You probably never call startListening in your code because this check `v.getId() == R.id.btn_speak` fails. You can remove the check or debug the method with additional log messages or a debugger.

Comment: No the button is working fine because as soon as i click the button then only the program executes and toast appears  @NikolayShmyrev

Comment: Which toast appears exactly?

Comment: Just the onRmsChanged one @NikolayShmyrev

Comment: and what is rmsdb value then?

Comment: It changes...sometimes even negative

Comment: It is better to be exact.

Comment: when i open the app its -2.12

Comment: And when you say something?

Comment: Doesnt change and neither onReadyForSpeech is called

Comment: Microphone is muted or broken then? Did you test the recording?

Comment: Yes i have tested it.Its working fine

Comment: Try another phone